# Resetting /usr/bin

Tags: terminal, catalina, bash, homebrew, zsh

So I was installing python3, pip, and a few other applications through Homebrew when I first got my Mac. I realized I was doing all this in /usr/bin and not /usr/local/bin, and I wanted to just to back to what was originally in /usr/bin. Nothing more, nothing less.
I re-installed the OS (from my local disk and also the internet) and I still have my "python3" and "pip3" applications within /usr/bin.

I think I also removed emacs, so when I type `which emacs` I get `emacs not found`.  I believe OS X comes with a native version of emacs that I also seem to have lost.
Any advice on how to get all the original contents of /usr/bin back, and remove what I've added?

Comment: Looking into this further, it might be a possibility that pip3 and python3 are actually now part of the Catalina release. In addition, the change to zsh has potentially removed emacs from the terminal. Still, it would be great if someone could confirm that these are actually intended in the /usr/bin folder!

Answer (score 2):

You can't fiddle with ***/usr/bin***: it's (SIP) restricted. To validate this understanding, just execute

`ls -laO /usr/bin`

So "***resetting***" this path as you seek to do is a non-starter.

***/usr/bin*** is full of binaries compiled by Apple themselves.  For instance, if you execute `/usr/bin/git --version` you'll see the git that lives here is an Apple thingy; nothing to do with ***Homebrew***.

I suspect that the programs were already installed by Apple in ***/usr/bin*** **BEFORE** you began installing stuff with ***Homebrew***.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `emacs` either: I presume it's not installed by default.

`pip3` and `python3` are in `/usr/bin` by default, though I believe they don't work until you've installed Xcode command line tools.